# Keep old sitemaps when upgrading to https?

Tags: https, google-search-console

I have successfully updated one of my sites to use https and I have updated both google and bing webmaster tools to these 4 sites:

http://example.com

http://www.example.com

https://example.com (everything is redirected to this one)

https://www.example.com

At this point should I remove the sitemap submissions for everything except for https://example.com or should I let them be?

Answer (score 0):

When you have 2 URL with same content from a domain, Google only index https url. So you can delete old sitemap and create new sitemap with https.

Source: [Indexing HTTPS pages by default](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/12/indexing-https-pages-by-default.html)